# Php MySQL into json - trying to put query into function

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to build a very basic API, I've got a query that pulls data from a MySQL view, I can echo the query out as json no problem but I want to put the query in a function in order to be able to call it from the API script...I'm just having some trouble putting the code into a function.

Here's the ode that works.....

```
<?php
$servername = "database.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,          $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from DB_Available_Dates";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["year"]. " - " . $row["Month"]. " " . $row["the_days"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

...and this is my attempt to put it into a function (that doesn't work!)...

```
//Connection as above
function available_dates() {
$sql = "SELECT * from DB_Available_Dates";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

$encodeArray = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $encodeArray[] = $row;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$dates = array();
$dates = json_encode($encodeArray);
return $dates;
}

available_dates();

$conn->close();
?>
```

I've just started with functions so I expect my errors to be quite comical!
...do I need to use echo to call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning an array in your code:

```
$dates = array();
$dates = json_encode($encodeArray);
return $dates;
```

You should simply echo the json_encode like this:

```
echo json_encode($encodeArray);
```

And then take care of the formatting/displaying (alternatively, you could do it like in your first example and echo back the output ready for displaying):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $encodeArray[] = $row["year"]. " - " . $row["Month"]. " " . row["the_days"].<br>";
}
```

and then

```
echo json_encode($encodeArray);
```

Comment: so, would the return value be 'return json_encode($encodeArray);' ?

Comment: If you're calling directly for the result (like in your first example that works) it is echo.
But if you're calling the function (in php), then you should return $encodeArray

And then when you're returning to jQuery, echo json_encode(available_dates())

Comment: I'm also getting an error that refers to the '$result = $conn' line - it says "Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Comment: ...fixed the error, it was a scope issue - so I put the connection inside the function - working properly now!!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing with the return value of your function.

You can echo it or put it in a variable.

```
echo available_dates();
```

or

```
print_r(available_dates());
```

or

```
$results = available_dates();
```

Comment: `print_r(available_dates());`, missed a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning anything,you should assign return value to some thing.You should call your function like this.

```
function available_dates() {
$sql = "SELECT * from DB_Available_Dates";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

$encodeArray = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $encodeArray[] = $row;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$dates = array();
$dates = json_encode($encodeArray);
return $dates;
}

$result=available_dates();
```